# Стрим сессии GNU Screen через http в режиме read only

Tags: linux, http, сеть, потоки-данных, gnu-screen

Есть процесс, который запущен внутри `GNU Screen`. Нужно, чтобы всё, что там происходит - можно было посмотреть через обычную http(s) ссылку. Как [Твитч](https://www.twitch.tv/), прямые трансляции на Youtube или VNC тоже в режиме `ro`. Только гораздо проще и полностью на своих мощностях. Если будет авторизация - вообще шикарно. `SSH` с любым уровнем доступа обеспечить не проблема.

Comment: а это вообще возможно?

Comment: Ну, технически я думаю, что да. Видео как-то же стримят, рабочий стол стримят, игры и прочее. А тут просто цепануться к сессии и всё что она выплюнет перевести в какой-нибудь webm через ffmpeg.

Comment: ах, вот вы про что. внесите, пожалуйста, информацию о том, что вы подразумевали под словом «стрим», прямо в вопрос.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, готово. Теперь понятнее?

Answer (score 0):

для того, чтобы **картинку** можно было ретранслировать куда-то (с помощью того же *vnc* или чего угодно иного), её «кто-то» должен **сформировать** (**нарисовать**).

как мне представляется, наиболее подходящий (в данном случае) инструмент для этого — какой-нибудь [«иксовый» эмулятор терминала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0).

запустите в эмуляторе *screen* и ретранслируйте изображение, **нарисованное** эмулятором, любым удобным вам способом.

Comment: Лично у меня проблем вообще нет - на моей рабочей машине установлен linux + virtualbox. И `sudo screen -x` делать вполне умею. Мне нужно, чтобы на вопрос "ну как там комп, когда будет готов?" кидалась ссылка, которая открывалась в браузере и человек мог смотреть в реалтайме (с мабилы в том числе) что же там с компом. Я подписан на RSS `Xming X Server`, зеркалю по rsync официальный сайт PuTTY. Если загнаться с обучением и научить людей пользоваться KyTTY - то проблема конечно исчезнет. Мне надо именно готовое (ну или хотя бы какие-то наработки) решение, чтобы порог вхождения был нулевой.

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=browser%20vnc%20viewer

Comment: Это первое, что пришло в голову. Отказался из-за сильно замороченной настройки и очень фиговой скорости.